# How do I decide on what key to join the tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables: `orders` and `customer`

`orders`:

```
+--------+-----------+------------+-------------+-------------+
| ord_no | purch_amt |  ord_date  | customer_id | salesman_id |
+--------+-----------+------------+-------------+-------------+
|  70009 |    270.65 | 2012-09-10 |        3001 |        5005 |
|  70002 |     65.26 | 2012-10-05 |        3002 |        5001 |
|  70004 |    110.50 | 2012-08-17 |        3009 |        5003 |
|  70005 |   2400.60 | 2012-07-27 |        3007 |        5001 |
|  70008 |   5760.00 | 2012-09-10 |        3002 |        5001 |
|  70010 |   1983.43 | 2012-10-10 |        3004 |        5006 |
|  70003 |   2480.40 | 2012-10-10 |        3009 |        5003 |
|  70011 |     75.29 | 2012-08-17 |        3003 |        5007 |
|  70013 |   3045.60 | 2012-04-25 |        3002 |        5001 |
|  70001 |    150.50 | 2012-10-05 |        3005 |        5002 |
|  70007 |    948.50 | 2012-09-10 |        3005 |        5002 |
|  70012 |    250.45 | 2012-06-27 |        3008 |        5002 |
+--------+-----------+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

`customer:`

```
+-------------+----------------+------------+-------+-------------+
| customer_id |   cust_name    |    city    | grade | salesman_id |
+-------------+----------------+------------+-------+-------------+
|        3002 | Nick Rimando   | New York   |   100 |        5001 |
|        3007 | Brad Davis     | New York   |   200 |        5001 |
|        3005 | Graham Zusi    | California |   200 |        5002 |
|        3008 | Julian Green   | London     |   300 |        5002 |
|        3004 | Fabian Johnson | Paris      |   300 |        5006 |
|        3009 | Geoff Cameron  | Berlin     |   100 |        5003 |
|        3003 | Jozy Altidor   | Moscow     |   200 |        5007 |
|        3001 | Brad Guzan     | London     |       |        5005 |
+-------------+----------------+------------+-------+-------------+
```

The problem I am trying to solve is

> Write a SQL statement to make a list with order no, purchase amount, customer name and their cities for those orders which order amount between 500 and 2000.

My Query for that is

```
SELECT ord_no, purch_amt, cust_name, city
FROM orders o
JOIN customer c
ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id
WHERE purch_amt BETWEEN 500 AND 2000
```

The above query gives correct answer as per [this](https://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/sql-joins-exercise-2.php) link.But I am not understanding on what column to join.

I have joined tables on `o.customer_id = c.customer_id` but what If I join both tables on `salesman_id`.

Why join on `customer_id` is correct and `salesman_id` is wrong. I wanted to understand *in general* how to decide columns on which join should occur when there are more than one common columns in tables between which join occurs( in this case `customer_id` and `salesman_id`)

Comment: The answer is that it depends on the design of the database as to how the data is stored, and it depends on the desired information as to how the information is queried.

Comment: @DaleBurrell But keeping it to my case why would have join on `salesman_id` would yield incorrect result

Comment: Well I can only guess because I don't know the intention behind the design, nor do I know exactly what information you are trying to obtain, but *in general* (if you consider the real world that this data is trying to model) a `customer` places an `order`. A `salesperson` might facilitate an order, but then its possible that an order could have a null salesperson. And a customer might have a default salesperson, but they might not always service that customer... only you know what the data exactly represents.

Comment: One end of the join should be to the PrimaryKey of a table.  When both ends are ForeignKeys (as proposed above using salesman_id) then the results are potentially many-to-many.  Lets take the above tables, and look at Order 70002.  When joining on salesman_id, it matches to both customer Rimando and Davis--is that what you want?  Same for order 70005 and 70008.

Comment: @donPablo Nicely explained !!

Comment: @donPablo & sql_learner Knowledge of keys or other constraints is not needed to query or join. The meanings of the base tables & result table matter. If there are constraints it just means that some additional expressions also return the right result that wouldn't otherwise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any rule of thumb to construct SQL query from a human-readable description?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947260/is-there-any-rule-of-thumb-to-construct-sql-query-from-a-human-readable-descript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question to answer: What does `customer.salesman_id` represent?

`orders.salesman_id` obviously tells us which salesman sold the stuff, while `orders.customer_id` tells us who bought it. So we join by `customer_id` in order to get the customer name for an order.

`customer.salesman_id` may mean something like the salesman who *usually* sells to the customer, which would be completely unrelated to the task.

It could also be, however, that a `customer_id` is only valid in combination with a `salesman_id`. So salesman #1 has a customer #1, but salesman #2 also has (another) customer #1. That would be composite keys, i.e. `salesman_id` + `customer_id` would be the customer's primary key and naturally the orders' foreign key. You'd have to join on both columns then. (However, it would be a bad idea then to call these columns ID. `salesman_number` + `customer_number` would be a better choice then, to indicate that they are not the tables' single IDs.)

So you see, it depends on the meaning of `customer.salesman_id`. In order to write queries, you must know your data model. As you say your solution was correct, `customer.salesman_id` obviously has a meaning unrelated to the given task.

Answer (score 2):

You use a *relational* database, where there is a relation between the orders and the customers (who placed these orders). There is also a relation to the salesman who handled each order. Depending on the information you need you need to join tables, and relevant details are linked by their *key*, their unique identifier in each table.